# Creating a patch in git gives some headaches

Tags: git, patch

I have cloned an upstream repository, started a bug-fixing branch on it, and spend quite a lot of time fiddling with it. Since I spent a lot of time with the branch and made all kinds of debugging and trivial changes to it, I branched a new branch from the more recent upstream master, and to that branch, merged the actual, finalized bug-fixing changes from my original bug-fixing branch, leaving out the cruft.

Now I'd like to create patch that has only the relevant changes relative to the recent upstream master commit. The relevant changes are all in the merge commit where I merged the original bug fixing branch to the newer one.

Now, when I run

```
git format-patch master
```

where master points to the commit from which I branched the newer fix branch, it creates multiple patch files with commits from the original bug fixing branch. I want just the single, concise bug-fixing changes, like those I get if I run

```
git diff master
```

To elaborate: the problem is not the fact that I get multiple patch files. The problem is that those patches contain all kinds of debug changes etc. that aren't included in the current branch.

What should I do to create a legit patch?

Comment: You wouldn't normally try to fixup like that via a merge commit.  You need to do rebase, or create new commit with the same tree as the merge commit but with only one parent going to master.

Comment: I see. After reading this: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase/ I can see why that would work better than my current workflow. If you write that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git format-patch` will create patches for all commits in the history you give it.

The normal git way to clean up your unpushed work is to use interactive rebase, via `git rebase -i`

Another option, if you wanted to end up with a single commit representing all of your work would be to do a squash merge with `git merge --squash`.

Given your current situation, if you want to preserve the contents of the merge commit and create a single new commit you could try the following (presuming you are checked out to your feature branch, and that it is pointing to the merge commit you created)

```
git reset --soft master
git commit
```

This would give you a single commit with your changes, and `format-patch` would work as expected.